# This device could not be tested at this time. Please upload a new APK

Tags: android, google-play-console, prelaunch

The google [pre-launch report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCU0m.jpg) has this message for 7 of 10 devices for the most recent apk of my app (version 0.0.6) - "This device could not be tested at this time. Please upload a new APK."

I've looked around but haven't found anything that gives me a clue as to what this message means.  Could some of the test devices be down?  Could it be an issue with my app - maybe something in the manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.truthbetolddesigns.herotracker"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Spell Links, Survey -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" /> <!-- Google Play In-App Billing -->

    <!-- SDK -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26"
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.travijuu.numberpicker.library" />

    <!-- Screens -->
    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        ...

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The previous .apk (version 0.0.5) had the [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtgF3.jpg) with 1/10 devices, and that was when I added In-App Billing and made it available to all countries outside the US, so could that be an issue?  I didn't have this issue before (versions 0.0.4 and before).

Any thoughts on what's causing this error message?

Comment: Is it possible to upload a new APK and run the test again?

Comment: Also for the previous version, were the same devices that weren't test as in the ones listed in the image your posted?

Comment: Correction: the previous version (0.0.5) only had the issue on 1 device. https://imgur.com/a/xPkq4  Surprisingly, the device that failed on version 0.0.5 (Galaxy J1 Ace) works on 0.0.6.

Comment: Interesting, that device which failed has succeeded in your latest version, I'm guessing it's an availability issue, probably there is another app that's using these devices for testing and so your app has to wait in line or something

Comment: To answer your first question, I suppose I could increment the version and re-upload.  I'd rather not, but I may do that if I can't figure this out.  I'm not sure if there's a way to get the pre-launch tests to re-run on the same .apk.

Comment: Honestly, I feel kind of disappointed with the Pre-launch report. I've been receiving this error for 6 uploades APKs, in different days and weeks. Always this error. It's happening to me this month of April 2019. Anyone with the same situation???

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en#device&landscape&app_play&pre_installed&app_openGL&app_andriod&x86&display_ads&app_without_activ&subscriptions&geolocation&) about the pre-launch reports:

It states that in "Test your APK":

> You'll usually receive test results shortly after uploading your APK.
>   In some cases, you'll receive results several hours after upload.

So I guess you'll just have to wait for it to update after a while. If not then probably contacting Support would be a good choice.

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this.  This may be the issue, or maybe not.  I've received an automatically generated email notice from google that the pre-launch report is done, so I'm not expecting any more tests to be done on the two most recent apks.  I could be wrong though.  I think they changed their pre-launch testing recently, so anything's possible...  I just wish that error notice was less cryptic.

Comment: @FreeMarketAnarchist any resolution on this? I just got this for the Oreo Pixel (Australia)...I don't understand what would have happened to cause that.

Comment: @TahoeWolverine I highly suspect that it was like ahasbini said - an issue with the test lab's availability.  I think you can still use the firebase lab to run a test on a particular device, unless they changed that recently. https://console.firebase.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved the issue buy changing **"default install location" setting** to "prefer external". It was set to "force internal" when it was giving this error. If you are using Unity game engine it is in the "Build Settings" -> "player settings". If you are working with Android Studio refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location)